# Spring 4.1.6 JdbcTemplate Blocking and Synchronus?

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have an injected `JDBCTemplate` instance, and the code basically executes

```
private JdbcTemplate template;

public OutputType getOutput(InputType input) {
    CallType call = new CallType(input);
    CallbackType callback = new CallbackType(input);

    OutputType output = (OutputType) template.execute(call, callback);
    ...
}
```

I assume the `execute` method actually connects to the database and retrieves the result.  However, I am having trouble finding out how the control flow works from the documentation.

Is the response from `execute` blocking (thread occupies a CPU core the entire time waiting for the database response)?  Is it synchronous, but not blocking (i.e. thread sleeps/is not scheduled until the response is ready)?  Is it asynchronous (`execute` returns immediately but output is incomplete/null, all database processing logic is in the callback)?

I have used several different databases so I am unsure of what actually happens in JdbcTemplate.  If my terminology is incorrect please let me know.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `JDBC` protocol itself is synchronous and blocking - it will block on socket I/O awaiting the database response. While this doesn't mean you couldn't asynchronously call a `JDBC` provider (manually spawn a separate thread, use actors, etc.), the actual connection to the database will always be synchronous.

`JDBCTemplate` is also fully synchronous and blocking, there is no thread magic going on under the hood.